# How to build a long command string?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, awk

I've a sequence of commands to be used along with lot of pipings, something like this:

```
awk '{ if ($8 ~ "isad") {print $2, $5, "SE"} else {print $2, $5, "ANT"} }' "/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log" | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | tr '[' '\0' | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] | sort -t' ' -s -k3
```

This basically filters the Apache log and prints three cols of info. First col is IP address, second is time, third is a string. The output could be sorted based on any column so, I need to use '-m' with sort for the time field.  Sorting order could also be reversed.

I want a string to store the arguments to sort, and let the combined strings get executed. Something like this:

```
$AWK_CMD | $SORT_CMD $SORT_KEY $SORT_REV
```

where

```
SORT_CMD="sort -t' '"
SORT_KEY="-k$1"      # $1 from cmd line arg
SORT_REV="$2"        # Either -r or blank
```

Am able to build such strings; when I echo it, it looks fine. Problem is, how to execute it? I get some errors like:

```
awk '{ if ($8 ~ "isad") {print $2, $5, "SE"} else {print $2, $5, "ANT"} }' "/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log" | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | tr '[' '\0' | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] | sort -t' ' -s -k3
Running ...
awk: '{
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

Please ignore if 'sort' doesn't sort properly, that can be fixed. I wish to know how I can build the final command string in steps. The ways I tried to execute this command in the script is by:

```
$final_cmd
`$final_cmd`
```

Edit: The script that I'm trying to use

```
KEY=$1      # Values {1, 2, 3}
REVERSE=$2  # Values {0, 1} 

SORT_CMD="sort -t' ' -s"
SORT_KEY="-k$KEY"
if [[ $KEY -eq 2 ]]
then
    SORT_KEY="-m -k2"
fi

if [[ $REVERSE -eq 1 ]]
then
    SORT_REV="-r"
else
    SORT_REV=
fi

final_cmd="awk '{ if (\$8 ~ \"isad\") {print \$2, \$5, \"SE\"} else {print \$2, \$5, \"ANT\"} }' $LOG_FILE '|' grep -v '127.0.0.1' '|' tr '[' '\0' '|' tr [:lower:] [:upper:] '|' $SORT_CMD $SORT_KEY $SORT_REV"

echo $final_cmd
echo "Running ..."
$final_cmd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different parts can be put in shell functions :

```
awkfilter() {
    awk '{ if ($8 ~ "isad") {print $2, $5, "SE"} else {print $2, $5, "ANT"} }'
}

toupper() {
    tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
}

dosort() {
    sort -t' ' -s -k3
}

awkfilter < /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log |
  grep -vF 127.0.0.1 |
  tr '[' '\0' |
  toupper |
  dosort
```

then you could make things optional more easily :

```
dosort() {
    rev=
    if [ "$2" = "reverse" ]
    then
        rev=-r
    fi
    sort -t' ' -s -k"$1" ${rev+"$rev"}
}
```

When your command-line is starting to be really long, writing it in a script and breaking it in parts (with functions) is usually really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Fussy! I too was trying to achieve the same, however, with string concatenation. But I think you gave me a better option. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `awk '{ ... }'` on a shell prompt or from a shell script, shell parses the quotes and passes the argument to `awk` w/o the quotes.  What happens is that you somehow run it with the quotes in parameter.

Edit: with your update to question, what you need is `sh -c "$final_cmd"`.

Comment: Like alex says, somehow the quote stays on execution. Can you (Barun) post the contents of $final_cmd and how you got it set?

Comment: Sure. I'm appending the script to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases where you are looking at wanting to execute commands with options kept in variables, use a shell that supports arrays.

Your example code, translated into `bash`, for example (note also that expansions of variables etc. need to be double quoted),

```
#!/bin/bash

key=$1      # Values {1, 2, 3}
reverse=$2  # Values {0, 1} 

sort_key=()
if [ "$key" -eq 2 ]; then
    sort_key=( -m  )
fi

if [ "$reverse" -eq 1 ]; then
    key+='r'
fi

sort_key+=( -k "$key" )

set -x

awk '$8 ~ "isad" { print $2, $5, ($8 ~ "isad" ? "SE" : "ANT") }' "$log_file" |
grep -Fv '127.0.0.1'          |
tr '[:lower:][' '[:upper:]\0' |
sort -t ' ' -s "${sort_key[@]}"
```

In this particular case, it may make more sense [to use functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7630/116858), but arrays would be useful for keeping e.g. indeterminate number of pathnames, or command line arguments created through modification of the script's own command line arguments.

Related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)